# Set JProgressBar TEXT color

Tags: java, swing, colors, jprogressbar

I have a JProgressBar called playerhealth. I the the color of the bar to green. This makes the text hard to see, so I want to set the color of the text inside the JProgressBar to be black.

I read that you can use UIManager to set the global color of JProgressBars, but I only want to do it for this one (and another, but that doesn't matter).

I also read [HERE](http://esus.com/setting-the-jprogressbar-colors/) that my only other option is to alter the JProgressBar class. How would I go about this?

Comment: you have to carefull and the look and feel you use!(different look&feel means different react.. After you set the bar StringPainted().. and .setForeground(Color.(your choice) if you don't see reactions use barname.setOpaque(true);

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the source code, this won't be easy.

The color is stored in the `BasicProgressBarUI` class:

- In the constructor the color is retrieved from the `UIManager` using a static method. Static method means you cannot overwrite the call.
- Colors are stored as private fields, and the class only expose protected getters, no setters. No setters mean you cannot call it externally.

The `ProgressBarUI` instance which is used for the `JProgressBar` is derived from the `UIManager` (`UIManager#getUI`), which is again a static method.

That leaves us with not that many options. What I think is a viable one is to use the `JProgressBar#setUI` method:

- This allows you to create your own UI instance
- This allows to override the protected getters

Major drawback for this approach is that it requires that you know up-front which Look and Feel your application will be using. For example if the application is using Metal, this would become

```
JProgressBar progressBar = ... ;
ProgressBarUI ui = new MetalProgressBarUI(){
  /**
   * The "selectionForeground" is the color of the text when it is painted
   * over a filled area of the progress bar.
   */
  @Override
  protected Color getSelectionForeground() {
    //return your custom color here
  }
  /**
   * The "selectionBackground" is the color of the text when it is painted
   * over an unfilled area of the progress bar.
   */
  @Override
  protected Color getSelectionBackground()
    //return your custom color here
  }
}
progressBar.setUI( ui );
```

Not 100% happy with this solution due to the major drawback of having to know the look-and-feel up-front.

Comment: I'm not sure what the look and feel does. If I don't really use this already, does it change anything?

Comment: You have/use a LookAndFeel, whether you want it or not. It is the look and feel which defines how your components look

Answer (score 0):

You could set the setStringPainted property to true:

```
progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
progressBar.setForeground(Color.blue);
progressBar.setString("10%");
```

Comment: The setStringPainted property determines whether or not the string will appear on the progress bar, not whether or not the string is painted a different colour.